# Javascript infinite loop bug

Tags: javascript

When the `addSell()` function is called it loops indefinitely. I know why: `i` never exceeds `select_array.length`. The question is how does `select_array` increase? The only thing I can think of is that `addSell()` is called when the div element is cloned causing recursion, but doing a console log suggests the function is only called once. Besides, `selectedIndex` isn't changed so the `onchange` event should never be fired. Any ideas?

```js
function addSel() {
  var select_array = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
  for (var i = 0; i < select_array.length; i++) {
    var select_name_array = select_array[i].name.split("#");
    var select_div = document.getElementById(select_array[i].name);
    var name_array = select_array[i].name.split('#');
    var div_clone = select_div.cloneNode(true);
    div_clone.id = select_name_array[0] + "#" + (Number(select_name_array[1]) + 1);
    div_clone.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].selectedIndex = -1;
    select_div.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', div_clone);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="select#1">
  <select name="select#1" onchange="addSel();">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="opt#1">Opt #1</option>
    <option value="opt#2">Opt #2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` gives you a live collection of all `select` elements. And you keep copying and adding more select elements.

Comment: Do you have an `addSel` vs `addSell` typo in your code? Or just in the question?

Comment: Sorry, `addSell()` is a typo in my explination. Should be `addSel()`

Comment: I suspected it may be updated live but how does the 'onchange' event get fired?

Comment: When you pick a new value in the <select> element. It's what kicks off the entire thing.

Comment: What is the intended behaviour (other than not looping forever)?

Comment: I wanted to add another select option to a list of existing options. A 'live collection' is not somethng I'd come across before so didn't really understand its behaviour.